# PHP if(value !== (value OR value)){}

Tags: php, html, variables

I'm trying to create an if() statement to catch any unwanted tampering or coding errors.

All parts are strings.

I've tried correct and incorrect values in the array, but it seams to default to true every time.. outputting the error.

```
if ($array['field'] !== ('b' || 'c')){
    echo 'An error has been encounterd <br/>';
    exit();
}
```

Any ideas? thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're comparing `$array['field']` to the **result** of `'b' || 'c'`.

You need to compare it to *each* of the things you want to match against.

You have to say "If the thing is not 'b' *and* it is also not 'c'".

```
if ($array['field'] !== 'b' && $array['field'] !== 'c'){
```

Comment: Brilliant! Big green tick is coming your way when the system allows

Answer (score 2):

try, this way:

```
if ($array['field'] !== 'b' && $array['field'] !==  'c'){
```

Comment: That's **never** going to be true. That shouldn't be an `||`.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!in_array($array['field'], array('b', 'c'))) {
    // ...
}
```